# Can I transfer an external hdd with Windows to go to internal sata hdd?

Tags: windows-to-go

I have successfully installed WindowsToGo win10 pro on an external hdd with enclosure. But bootup is slow cause it's just USB. Can I remove the hdd from the enclosure and put it directly inside my computer?